# Toolbar buttons for specific Richtext components inside custom Gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have a custom Gutenberg block with multiple RichText components inside. I need to show specific ToolbarButtons for different RichText components, in a similar UX to the native approach for formatTypes, for example:

```
allowedFormats={['core/italic']}
```

Will show the italic control for the RichText element. I do not wish to registerFormatType as these controls would save block attributes rather than adjust richtext formatting. It's led me to a few experiments, where I have an almost working concept, pseudocoded here:

```
edit : () => {

    const [isRichText1Focus,setIsRichText1Focus] = useState(false)
    const [isRichText2Focus,setIsRichText2Focus] = useState(false)

    return (
        
        <>
        
            {isRichText1Focus && (

                <BlockControls>
                    <ToolbarGroup>
                        <ToolbarButton
                            icon="test"
                            title="Title"
                            onClick={ () => {
                                //Change a block attribute 
                            } }
                        />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                </BlockControls>

            )}

            {isRichText2Focus && (

                <BlockControls>
                    <ToolbarGroup>
                        <ToolbarButton
                            icon="test 2"
                            title="Title 2"
                            onClick={ () => {
                                //Change another block attribute 
                            } }
                        />
                    </ToolbarGroup>
                </BlockControls>

            )}

            <div className='blockName'>

                <RichText
                    onBlur={() => {
                        setIsRichText1Focus(false)
                    }}
                    ...//other params
                    unstableOnFocus={() => {
                        setIsRichText1Focus(true)
                    }}
                />

                <RichText
                    onBlur={() => {
                        setIsRichText2Focus(false)
                    }}
                    ...//other params
                    unstableOnFocus={() => {
                        setIsRichText2Focus(true)
                    }}
                />

            </div>
        </>

    ]) 

}
```

You can see my attempt here is to only show certain block control buttons when in focus of a RichText area. However, it isn't possible to get a reliable 'onBlur' that also covers the toolbar itself, so onBlur on the RichText component is inappropriate. There is clearly a concept within Gutenberg for a reliable focus/ blur as registerFormatType and the formatTypes API handle this well. Can I replicate this somehow with this approach? Or is this approach just too hacky, and I should take a different approach completely? Would be wonderful to use the native Toolbar rather than create my own UI alongside.

Comment: Have you tried/considered block variations? If the alternative versions of the RichText are all the same except for the tools, then variations might be another way..

Comment: They're not quite right for this use case—where we have a single block with multiple RichText components inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach using [InnerBlocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/) and [block variations](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-variations/) by creating a custom Parent and Child block.

The Parent block is like a wrapper block, only containing a `InnerBlocks` setup, to store the custom Child block variants via a `template`. This enables you to specify the initial state of the Child blocks and their attributes.

The Child block contains a `RichText` component, with a block attribute that defines the `Toolbar` content to change via block variations. This way, the correct toolbar is rendered when the RichText is selected; the focus remains at the block level and no need for `setState()` or potential bad `setState()` calls.

As you are using Block Controls, I would implement them at the block level. If you also look into how Block Controls can be added to existing [block filters](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/), eg  `wp.hooks.addFilter('editor.BlockEdit', ...)` it may help you see a different way to approach the problem.